# Add buttons programmatically to table view cells

Tags: ios, uitableview, uibutton

I can add and delete cells to my table view. How to have two buttons for each cell that's added?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add the button as subview for your cell. That's it. I have given the sample:

```
//Create your cell then do the following    
UIButton *newBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[newBtn setFrame:CGRectMake(10,5,55,55)];
[newBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(yourSelector:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[cell addSubview:newBtn];
```