# How to add button to cell in table view

Tags: ios

I need to add two clickble buttons in a cell of my table view.
Each cell also has a view in which labels and images are there. Basically I want two buttons so that on click of one button table 1 is loaded and on click of other button table 2 can be loaded.
Thankx in advance.

Comment: in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method, create the two buttons and add like this
`[cell.contentView addSubView:button1];`
`[cell.contentView addSubView:button2];`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add buttons programatically to table view cells.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7721364/add-buttons-programatically-to-table-view-cells)

Comment: @Saksha: google it before posting a question. There are so many question already available in SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is sample code may it help you

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:[NSString   stringWithFormat:@"Cell %i",indexPath.section]];

    if (cell == nil) {

        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell %i",indexPath.section]] autorelease];

    }


    NSLog(@"i am here in table function..........now");


    //cell.textLabel.text = [data objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];

    search_items *pro = [searchCount objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

    cell.textLabel.text = pro.s_showroomName;



    UIButton* aButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];

aButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0,150,44);  

        [aButton setTag:[indexPath row]];

        [aButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


    [cell.contentView addSubview:aButton];

        return cell;
}

-(void)buttonClicked:(UIButton*)sender {
    int tag = sender.tag;

///and rest code here.....

}
```