# How to add a button in each row of a dynamic table?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am re-using an Objective-C code where there is a dynamic tableView that display bluetooth devices in the area.
I would like to add a button on each row of this tableView that would trigger an action and display a content at the bottom of the screen.

The current and interesting part of code is

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyIdentifier"];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"MyIdentifier"];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    }

    CLBeacon *beacon = (CLBeacon*)[self.beacons objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *proximityLabel = @"";
    switch (beacon.proximity) {
        case CLProximityFar:
            proximityLabel = @"Far";
            break;
        case CLProximityNear:
            proximityLabel = @"Near";
            break;
        case CLProximityImmediate:
            proximityLabel = @"Immediate";
            break;
        case CLProximityUnknown:
            proximityLabel = @"Unknown";
            break;
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = proximityLabel;

    NSString *detailLabel = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Major: %d, Minor: %d, RSSI: %d, UUID: %@",
                             beacon.major.intValue, beacon.minor.intValue, (int)beacon.rssi, beacon.proximityUUID.UUIDString];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = detailLabel;

    return cell;
}
```

I am wondering what would be the best way to do it, and where to insert the button in this code.
I am not familiar with Objective-C dev and looking for all kind of example/illustration for this problem.

Comment: there are many answers : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7721364/add-buttons-programatically-to-table-view-cells

Comment: Add the `UIButton` to your prototype cell in your storyboard. Add the `IBAction` for the `UIButton` to your custom cell subclass.

Comment: There is not prototype in the storyboard. This is a TableView and each beacon found is displayed in a new row. I would like each button to call a function and to pass to it a variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can add your button in your cell's init part, that is

```
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"MyIdentifier"];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    // create your button and add it to your cell
    UIButton *button = ....
    [cell.contentView addSubview:button];
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I have added the button, and now I am wondering how to set an action on this button. Not sure how to do it either